# How do I use Einstein notation to propose a rule for $MX=0$ and proving it's linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Let  $$M = \begin{bmatrix}a^1_1 & a^1_2&....& a^1_k\\a^2_1 & a^2_2 & .... & a^2_k \\ : & : & .... &: \\ a^r_1 & a^r_2 & .... & a^r_k\end{bmatrix} \quad\text{ and } \quad  X =\begin{bmatrix}x^1 \\ x^2 \\ : \\ x^k\end{bmatrix}$$
Use Einstein summation notation to propose a rule for $MX$ so that $MX = 0$ is equivalent to the linear system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a^1_1x^1 + a^1_2x^2+....+a^1_kx^k = 0\\a^2_1x^1+ a^2_2x^2+....+ a^2_kx^k =0 \\  :\\ a^r_1x^1+a^r_2x^2 +....+a^r_kx^k = 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Show that your rule for multiplying a matrix by a vector obeys the linearity property.

---

#### Progress

I understand Einstein's notation, but I cannot apply it correctly here. I can express $X$ with Einstein's notation, but not $M$. Furthermore I know to set the summation(s) to zero.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: @Peter: I understand Einstein's notation, but I cannot apply it correctly here. I can express x with Einstein's notation, but not M. Furthermore I know to set the summation(s) = o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $i$th element of the vector $MX$ is simply $M_{ij}X_j$ or where $M_{ij}$ is the matrix element in $i$th row and $j$th column. Since $MX=0$, it can be written in Einstein notation as $$M_{ij}X_j=0$$